# How can I handle mailto and tel in android webview

Tags: java, android

I already make a java WebView for my website, this website in the footer the phone number and the email address when I click in it they told me (the webpage at tel could not be loaded because err_unknown_url_scheme), What should i do ?

MainActivity.Java

```
package xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try
        {
            Objects.requireNonNull(this.getSupportActionBar()).hide();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException ignored){}

        //find the view
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        // to load all the web page in app itself use this
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView.loadUrl("https://www.ezyadvs.com");

        WebSettings webSettings =webView.getSettings();

        //if your website is using any javascript that needs to load some script then you need to enable javascript in android application
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // if any previous webpage exist then onback pressed will take care of it

        if(webView.canGoBack())
        {
            webView.goBack();
        }else{

            //else it will exit the application
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40734768/mailto-does-not-working-in-android-webview, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338305/android-webview-tel-links-show-web-page-not-found

Comment: I cant do edit !

Comment: What can you edit?

Comment: I cant edit the code with your comment it give me error

Comment: I sent you 2 links to similar questions. You can read them and try to apply to your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android WebView "tel:" links show web page not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338305/android-webview-tel-links-show-web-page-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in .kt (kotlin) :

```
            this.webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {

                    //add condition startsWith("tel:") or startsWith("mailto:")
                    if (url!!.startsWith("whatsapp:")) {
                        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                        intent.data = Uri.parse(url)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        return true
                    } 
                    return false
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm talking about .java, Its the same ?

Comment: yeah, they have a similar syntax